# Persisting The Eye Icon in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Can we persist the eye icon for password field in Internet Explorer 11? It should not display after typing the password , it should be there from the beginning i.e. without navigating to the password field also it should show. Can we do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are talking about an eye icon which displayed while entering the password in the field.

As per it's default behavior, it will only display while user enters the password for first time. It will not display before entering the password and it will not display again once user input the password.

There is no way to display it continuously before entering the password.

[image]

From your description, it looks like you want to show it to user to make them remember for entering the password.

But this icon is not made for this purpose. You should use some kind of validation on your form controls. so if user try to continue without entering the password then user get message from your validation code.

Comment: The gif is correct.. I am facing the same issue.. I just want to persist that eye button in the browser, specifically I want some IE specific changes to the code to make it visible permanently even when I am not using the field .. Now I am asking this because in crome the icon is persisting.. and yes I am not looking for any validation thing here... I just want to persist the eye icon on the form even if I am not using the field... please let me know if there is any solution ... Thank you for showing interest.

Comment: As I informed you before, We cannot control that behavior and there is no any way to do it. As a work around, you can try to show similar kind of icon just beside your password input and develop a logic in JS for showing and hiding it as per requirement.

Comment: Yeah doing the same trial and error :)   IE does not support JavaScript fuctions fully

Comment: You can create a new thread for it as it is a different issue and try to mark the helpful suggestion on this thread and help to close it. Thanks for your understanding.